# Django; Is it possible to ignore this error? django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory:

Tags: python, django

I see the same error many people have seen.

> django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration message.0001_initial is applied before its dependency users.0001_initial on database 'default'.

Seems like the cause is because I'm using CustomUser model (using `django-allauth`).

I already delete all the `migration` folders and `sqlite3` and tried some ways other people answered. But I cannot avoid this error.

Seems like I was successful in avoiding this error (I have no idea how I did.)
And because the migration files still remains on my gitHub, I saw them and all the files look the same as the ones I created before.  I'm wondering if I can ignore this error and waring. If not, what is the way to avoid this error?

what I did
using `--fake` when doing migrations

hiding `django.admin` when doing migrations

applying `zero`

all things failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved the problem.

What I did is applying migration into the app `CustomUser` model is located, and then applying migration into other apps. And then I did `python manage.py migrate`.

Other orders doesn't work for me.